# Event "After cloning a node" by node clone module is not working

Tags: 7, rules

I am trying to use the event "After cloning a node" provided by [Node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) module for [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) integration but its not working.Do any one came across this issue before?

I have created the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2212039) as a bug in issue queue of node clone module.

Any pointers on this?

Comment: two years later and the bug is still there :-) Did you find a combination of action/conditions for a replacment of this event?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be confirmed by some other users also now.

[Comment #9 of that issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2212039#comment-9403685) contains a patch that might possibly solve it.

Another possible solution (patch) is included in [comment #8 of that issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2212039#comment-9344895), proposed by the module maintainer. With a comment like "*Not sure about the use case ...*"

The issue is currently in status "**Needs review**", so maybe you might (still) have an appropriate use case to get that issue in RTBC status?

Comment: Thanks Pierre for the update, I stopped following the thread, will give a try sometime!